# Difference in response time between HTTPclient 3.1 and HTTP client 4 in jmeter

Tags: https, httpclient, jmeter, apache-httpclient-4.x

i am testing my website using HTTPS. The response time is higher when i used the default implementation. The response time is getting reduced if i use implementation as HTTPclient 3.1. Why there is a difference in response time between HTTPclient 4 and HTTPclient 3.1? To test my website with https, do i need to use HTTPclient 4 or HTTPclient 3.1 ? Which will provide me the exact response time as like in browser?

Below is my sample test plan,

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [HTTP Request documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

> HTTP Request - this has an implementation drop-down box, which selects the HTTP protocol implementation to be used:
>   Java - uses the HTTP implementation provided by the JVM. This has some limitations in comparison with the HttpClient implementations - see below.
>   HTTPClient3.1 - uses Apache Commons HttpClient 3.1. This is no longer being developed, and support for this may be dropped in a future JMeter release.
>   HTTPClient4 - uses Apache HttpComponents HttpClient 4.x.
>   Blank Value - does not set implementationon HTTP Samplers, so relies on HTTP Request Defaults if present or on jmeter.httpsampler property defined in jmeter.properties
>   The Java HTTP implementation has some limitations:
>   There is no control over how connections are re-used. When a connection is released by JMeter, it may or may not be re-used by the same thread.
>   The API is best suited to single-threaded usage - various settings are defined via system properties, and therefore apply to all connections.
>   There is a bug in the handling of HTTPS via a Proxy (the CONNECT is not handled correctly). See Java bugs 6226610 and 6208335.
>   It does not support virtual hosts.

**It's better to use `HTTPClient4` implementation**.

However if you need your requests to be as much **like a real browser** as possible you need to consider using following components:

- In [HTTP Request Default](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)s tell JMeter to retrieve all embedded resources and do in using thread pool of 2-5 requests (as real browsers do)
- Use [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) - to simulate browser cookies and to deal with cookie-based authentication
- Use [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) - to set user agent string, content type, accept language, etc. headers.
- Use [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) - to simulate browser cache

Comment: Hi dmitri.. I am already using all the elements which you mentioned to act like a browser. My use case is to compare my site between http and https. But my real concern is that when i use HTTPclient 3.1, the response time is nearer to the response time of http. When i use HTTPclient 4, the response time is five time the response of http. As you mentioned, there will not be support for HTTPclient 3.1 in future. Why there is huge difference in response time between HTTPclient 3.1 and HTTPclient 4 ?

Comment: It looks like that you're experiencing the issue tracked as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-925. I've tested HttpClient 3 and 4 implementations locally against SSL-enabled Apache server and response times are nearly the same. I'd suggest to measure time from real browser and choose closest implementation. Personally I'd go for HttpClient 4 but you're fine to use HTTPClient 3.1 - no one is going to remove previous JMeter versions from download area and HTTPClient 3.1 is still present in the latest JMeter 2.11

Comment: Thank you dmitri for your valuable explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Benchmarks I made against local site in HTTPs didn't at all confirm what is being said here.

HttpClient 4 is even now faster than HttpClient 3.1 particularly since 2.10 which fixed an issue in this area:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55023

And even more with 2.11 which made performance improvements:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55857
- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55865

Also as you can see issue referred to by Dmitri is closed as "Not an issue" as reported problem was wrong.

If you confirm you are not in the cases described in the JIRA, then describing how you are leading your test might help.

Comment: Hi ubik, i had problems in 2.9, so i tried with 2.11. Still i am facing the same problem. My test plan contains few request (HTTPS) and i included cookie manager, concurrent pool size as 4. With HTTPclient 4 am getting response time much higher than httpclient3.1. I dint change any SSL configurations in jmeter.property or system.property. my server is also having higher specification. Can you suggest me the solution to get exact response time? Do i need to change any ssl configuration in property file?

Comment: Added test plan in my question

Comment: Hi ubik, any comments? I also included sample test plan.

Comment: You didn't set which website you were hitting abc.com is just a fake one right? is it internal or external ?

Comment: It is internal website